# Eclipse throwing error when copying and pasting

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 3.5 SR2 for Java EE developers. Each time I press control+C or control+V for the first time after I open a file I get an error. After I close the error, I can successfully copy and paste. The error message made me believe that it was related to the Mylyn plugin, but I uninstalled it and still no difference. Has anyone else experience this problem? I also have the subclipse, adobe flex builder, and maven plugins installed.

> The
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.hyperlinks.detectors.url'
>   extension from plug-in
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui' to the
>   'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors'
>   extension point failed to load the
>   hyperlink detector.
>
> Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui was
>   unable to load class
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.editors.TaskUrlHyperlinkDetector.
>
> An error occurred while automatically
>   activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (520).
>
> The
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.hyperlink.detector.stack'
>   extension from plug-in
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks' to the
>   'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors'
>   extension point failed to load the
>   hyperlink detector.
>
> Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks
>   was unable to load class
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.java.tasks.JavaStackTraceHyperlinkDetector.
>
> org/eclipse/mylyn/tasks/ui/AbstractTaskHyperlinkDetector
>
> The
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui.hyperlinks.detectors.task'
>   extension from plug-in
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui' to the
>   'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors'
>   extension point failed to load the
>   hyperlink detector.
>
> Plug-in org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui was
>   unable to load class
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.editors.TaskHyperlinkDetector.
>
> An error occurred while automatically
>   activating bundle
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui (520).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.mylyn/msg00747.html) alludes to a similar error and mentions [**bug 214301**](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=214301) (which is **solved in [Egit 2.3.0, February 2013](https://github.com/eclipse/egit/releases/tag/v2.3.0.201302130906)**)

> this looks like an inconsistent install of Mylyn causing this exception.
>   Could you check which versions of the Mylyn features you have installed (

```
Help >
About > Configuration Details
```

> )?

---

Example of inconsistent Mylyn installation:

> - Mylyn 2.1 is installed
> - The Task List (mylyn-feature) and the structure bridges (ide-feature,
>     pde-feature etc.) are updated to 2.2
> - The Focused UI (context-feature) remains at version 2.1

---

Solution:

> **update again and ensure that you get the "Mylyn Bridge: Eclipse SDK" feature**
>
> First, try running the update again via

```
Help -> Software Updates -> Search
for new features
```

> .. and ensure that all of the Mylyn features have been updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "Eclipse Helios", just update the Mylyn. It would fix the issue.

1. Help -> Check for updates -> Select Mylyn entries -> Next -> Next and see the progress till it completes installation of new updates. Then
2. Restart your eclipse.