# Eclipse mylyn error while cut and paste, open and close files?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn, phpeclipse

I have this annoying error mylyn message on eclipse luna 4.4,

> The 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.hyperlink.detector.stack' extension from
>   plug-in 'org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks' to the
>   'org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.hyperlinkDetectors' extension
>   point failed to load the hyperlink detector.
>   org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.java.tasks.JavaStackTraceHyperlinkDetector
>   cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jface.text.hyperlink.IHyperlinkDetector

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586778/eclipse-throwing-error-when-copying-and-pasting) seems to be the answer for this error,

> Solution:
>
> update again and ensure that you get the "Mylyn Bridge: Eclipse SDK"
>   feature
>
> First, try running the update again via Help -> Software Updates ->
>   Search for new features

But I have **no** Software Updates on my luna version. I only have **Check for Updates**. There is **no** updates available for Mylyn at all even I click on **Check for Updates**.

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer you link is quite old, 'Check for Updates' is the new name for 'Software Updates'.

Comment: yeah... none of them fix the problem though. eclipse sucks. you spend more time fixing bugs/ problems/ errors than coding!